# Composer install force download as tar instead of zip

Tags: laravel, composer-php, unzip, envoyer.io

We are using envoyer for laravel project. Now every deploy takes almost 5 minutes. About 40s to download and unpack a new release.

The install composer dependencies takes about 150s. We figured out that it is actually loading it from the cache which are zipfiles. Unfortunately the server isn't dedicated because what we found out that unzip is just really slow. We tested the same thing on a server with dedicated hardware and it was really fast.

We're wondering if there's an option to download the composer packages in another format than zip. Something like tar.gz?

Comment: Would that solve your problem? If 5 minutes is really that much of a problem, just get a better server. They cost a couple of tens of dollars per year which easily compensates the 8 unbillable hours of optimizing your shared host to still not do what you want.

Comment: Well shouldn't it just work properly? Why only restrict it to a zip format?

Comment: They don't: https://superuser.com/questions/936802/composer-install-tar-gz . Still, maybe a tar.gz saves you about 10 seconds. Is that worth it? Your choice ofc.

Comment: Well unpacking the entire repo, which is a tar.gz, is done in seconds. So it will save more then just 10 seconds.

Comment: Okay cool! Didn't know the difference was that big :)

Comment: Yeah well probaly the issue is with unzip in a virtual environment. But thanks anyway :)